# What is Kasisto?

Tags: p2p, payment-integration, monero-wallet-rpc

What is Kasisto?

1. Is there a demo available?
2. Is it open source? If so where can I see the source code?
3. Who is the developer?
4. How can I become a beta tester?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Kasisto is a web app enabling you to receive person to person Monero payments in small cafes, bars or shops. It will accept unconfirmed payments which makes it pretty much instant, but also means you should only accept smaller amounts since there's always a chance of a transaction not getting mined.

I'm the developer, the source is on GitHub: [amiuhle/kasisto](https://github.com/amiuhle/kasisto). There's also a [testnet demo](https://amiuhle.github.io/kasisto/).

At the moment, you can become a tester simply by cloning the repository and running it locally, connecting to a `monero-wallet-rpc` with your view-only wallet.
I will update the documentation on GitHub over the next couple of days, please be patient.

Once it's production ready, the latest release will be running on a public server, while `monero-wallet-rpc` (and probably `monerod`) will run on your local network. Configuration of Kasisto (like URL to wallet rpc) will be stored in the browser, so nothing will leave your local network.

Comment: Very cool project, thanks for making it open source!

Comment: What would prevent a transaction from being mined? Wouldn't it eventually get mined, even if it took a long time?

Comment: @AustinWhitelaw I think it will timeout eventually. I'll document this in the README as soon as I have some idea how likely this is.