# How do I start accepting monero at my restaurant/store?

Tags: transaction-confirmation, payment-integration

What is the process for accepting monero at stores?  I would love to start accepting Monero.

Comment: Thank you for the info!  If you create a pool for your clients, I would be glad to mine it.  Would that help the validation process?  That way you can keep the cost low for the merchants and still get an income for your project.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways you can go:

- run your own Monero infrastructure
- use a payment processor to do it for you

The first one has you running a Monero node and wallet, and use monero RPC to manage payment ids, track incoming transactions, etc. There are early plugins for some common store software: https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerowp/releases/tag/0.1 for Woocommerce, and a work in progress for Prestashop: https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerops, both by the same author (serhack). You can also do custom integration, and you can find instructions on using the RPC at https://getmonero.org/get-started/accepting/. Likely you will need help if you go this route, and the people in #monero (Freenode IRC) will be able to give a hand should you need to.

A variant of "doing it yourself" if all payments are face to face is to use the monero GUI alone, or Kasisto ([What is Kasisto?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/what-is-kasisto)): those have a "payment tracker", in which you can generate a payment id for a customer, and scan the blockchain for incoming payments matching that payment and owed amount.

The second one requires you to pay a service provider such as https://www.coinpayments.net/ or, at some point in the (hopefully near) future, https://payb.ee to handle Monero-to-fiat conversion.

Comment: Didnt knew about Kasisto, great tool for simple things